# How fix a TypeError?

Tags: javascript

There is a function in my script which is coded to create a button in a div container, but i get a type error when i try to append it in my div container.

i have tried to change the name of the div container but it does not work.

```
function EndGame(){
    var LogOut = document.createElement('button'); 
    var Form  = document.getElementsByClassName('Form');
    LogOut.textContent = 'Logout';
    Form.appendChild(LogOut);
    LogOut.addEventListener('click',ReStart);
}
```

the function gives me a TypeError saying

"TypeError: Form.appendChild is not a function"

Comment: Have a look at variable and function naming conventions

Answer (score 2):

[getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns a collection of HTML elements, not just the first one, as you seem to expect.

Replace this:

```
var Form  = document.getElementsByClassName('Form');
```

by this:

```
var Form  = document.getElementsByClassName('Form')[0];
```